# `ObjOrObjs` type hint in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

i often find myself with a parameter that can be either a single thing or multiple things. here are some short examples:

```
def f(str_or_strs: str | list[str]):
    pass

def g(num_or_nums: int | list[int]):
    pass
```

i feel like there should be way that to write that type hint as one, single type hint, e.g.:

```
def h(id_or_ids: ObjOrObjs[int]):
    pass
```

and have the type checker pick up on this.

i've tried things like:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
class ObjOrObjs(Union[T, list[T]]):
    pass


class ObjOrObjs:
    def __class_getitem_(cls, item: T) -> T, list[T]]]:
        return Union[item, list[item]]


L = TypeVar('L', bound=list[T])
class ObjOrObjs(Generic[T], Generic[L]):
    pass


class OneOrMore(Generic[T], Iterable[T], Type[T]):
    pass
```

but when i run this code, e.g.:

```
def h(id_or_ids: ObjOrObjs[int]):
    pass

h(3)
h([4])
```

the type checker always complains that these types passed in to `h` are wrong.

so, my sticking point: i can't figure out a valid way to represent `ObjOrObjs` in code.
any thoughts on how to do this? thank you.

note: i'm currently just using pycharm's built-in type checking.

Comment: What if you used `*args`? I'm not very familiar with typing so sorry if this isn't helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `ObjOrObjs = Union[T, list[T]]`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that sorta works, except then i can't specify the thing i want it to be. i.e. can't do something like  `def h(OneOrMore[int])`

Comment: @acushner huh? yes you can. `def h(paramter: ObjOrObjs[int]) -> whaterver: ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh wow, that _does_ work! i "tested" it incorrectly earlier in some dumb way that definitely didn't work. unfortunately pycharm can't figure it out, but this is exactly what i wanted. thank you! do you mind answering so i can accept/give you internet points?